# yii2 urlManager + .htaccess = subdomain how to?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2, subdomain, yii-url-manager

here's the challenge: i need to make the imitation of subdomains. Actually all the "subdomains" in the project are simple actions of the main SiteController like

example.com/index.php/site/subsite?id=subname

example.com/index.php/site/about?id=subname

example.com/index.php/site/contacts?id=subname

etc. I need them to look like

subname.example.com/

subname.example.com/about

subname.example.com/contacts

etc. I have included urlManager rules like this:

`'rules' => [
                'http://<id:\w+>.site.com/about' => 'site/about',
                'http://<id:\w+>.site.com/contacts' => 'site/contacts',
                'http://<id:\w+>.site.com' => 'site/subsite',
                        ],`

And made a .htaccess file that is :

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*).site.com [NC]
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} "^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$.site.com" "site.com/index.php/subsite?id=$1" [L]`
But it (predictably) doesnt work as i am not strong in rewrite rules. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: why not use a yii2-advance-app and have each app serve a domain??

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1. Configure one virtual host on web server to host all subdomain and point to the Yii2 application
2. Write component **Subdomain.php** and put it in **frontend\components**

```php
<?php

namespace frontend\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

class Subdomain extends Component {
    private $_subdomain = false;

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        list($this->_subdomain) = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->_subdomain;
    }
}

?>
```

3. In **frontend\config\main.php** in the '**components**' section add:

```php
    'subdomain' => [
        'class' => 'frontend\components\Subdomain'
    ],
```

4. Then in the project where I need subdomain I would use:

```php
$subdomain = \Yii::$app->subdomain;
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am using a basic template

Comment: @IvanWheatman then in namespace just replace 'frontend' with 'app', and instead of 'frontend' folder put in the main folder of your project like /var/www/yourapp/components/ and /var/www/yourapp/config/

Comment: probably i have missed something in the description, or there is some misunderstanding between us here :) i do not need to use subdomains - the point is that i need urlManager to parse the links like
_subdomain.example.com_
to 
_example.com/index.php/site/subsite?id=subdomain_